# Using the definition, compute the partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Consider the following function:
>
> $$f : R^3 → R,\space\space f(x, y, z) = \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^3}$$
>
> Using the definition, compute the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0).$

**Solving with respect to $x$**

**Definition:**

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y,z)-f(x,y,z)}{h}$$

Substiuting our function $f$ in the definition, we see;

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{((x+h)^2+y^2+z^2)^3}-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}{h}$$

Using the fact that $f(0,0,0)=0,$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{((0+h)^2+0+0)^3}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{h^3}{h}\right)=\lim_{h\to 0}h^2=0$$

We would then find the same for $y$ and $z$.

**Is my solution correct?**

Comment: You mean to have $|h|^3$ where you have $h^3$? (There's a corresponding correction to the next term ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correct. The definition of derivaitve includes a limit:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y,z)-f(x,y,z)}{h}$$

Perform now the needed calculations and take the limit. Of course, the quantity $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ must not depend on $h$

Comment: Of course, I forgot to put in the $\lim$ at the start of my calculations, thank you.

Comment: @james15c Even then, don't forget to take it at the end!

Answer (score 1):

Denote: $x^2+y^2+z^2=t$ for simplicity of calculations.

The partial derivative is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{((x+h)^2+y^2+z^2)^3}-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}}{h} \\
&=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{((x+h)^2+y^2+z^2)^3-(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}{h[\sqrt{((x+h)^2+y^2+z^2)^3}+\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}]} \\
&\stackrel{*}=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{(2xh+h^2)[2xh+h^2+t)^2+(2xh+h^2+t)t+t^2]}{h(\sqrt{(2xh+h^2+t)^3}+\sqrt{t^3})} \\
&=\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac{(2x+h)[2xh+h^2+t)^2+(2xh+h^2+t)t+t^2]}{\sqrt{(2xh+h^2+t)^3}+\sqrt{t^3}} \\
&=\frac{(2x+0)[2x\cdot 0+0^2+t)^2+(2x\cdot 0+0^2+t)t+t^2]}{\sqrt{(2x\cdot 0+0^2+t)^3}+\sqrt{t^3}} \\
&=\frac{2x[3t^2]}{2\sqrt{t^3}} \\
&=3xt^{1/2} \\
&=3x\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\end{align}
Note: At $*$ it was used:
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$

Comment: Good answer, but feels like overkill, since we only need it at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$

Comment: Until 4th edit and I had been typing then, it was $(x,y,z)\ne (0,0,0)$. Anyway, I gave a general answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Mattos, thank you for aligning, looks nice.

Comment: @farruhota No worries.